# How can i get a Activity Name before axecute

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am executing a pipeline in ADF and I need to capture the name of an activity after it is executed, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to create a one sp with below syntax
INSERT INTO [IM_CONTROL_T].[ADF_ERROR_LOG_T]
(
[PipelineName],
[PipelineID],
[ActivityName],
[ActivityID],
[ErrorCode],
[ErrorDescription],
[ActivityStartTime],
[PipelineStartTime],
[ErrorLoggedTime]
)
VALUES
(
@PipelineName ,
@PipelineID ,
@ActivityName ,
@ActivityID ,
@ErrorCode ,
@ErrorDescription ,
@ActivityStartTime ,
@PipelineStartTime ,
@ErrorLoggedTime
)
and call this sp after your activity and in pipeline name type (@pipeline().Pipeline) & activity name just hardcode it - like lookup in my case.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgyFO.png
```